# Successive chunking of a list

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style

I have shuffled and used the output of `Range[20]` in order to create this minimal example:

t = {19, 4, 12, 1, 17, 13, 7, 14, 10, 11, 6, 18, 20, 15, 16, 3, 8, 5,
2, 9};

I would like to successively apply a function to select parts of this list and remove the entries selected. Let's say that the function is `TakeLargest[#,UpTo[4]]&`. I would like to keep taking UpTo the four largest elements till the list is empty. Here is my code for it.

```
t = {19, 4, 12, 1, 17, 13, 7, 14, 10, 11, 6, 18, 20, 15, 16, 3, 8, 5, 
   2, 9};
Module[{temp = t, pos, res},
 Reap[While[Length@temp > 0,
    pos = Flatten@(Position[temp, #] & /@ TakeLargest[temp, UpTo[4]]);
    Echo[pos, "pos="];
    res = {temp[[Sort@pos]], 
      ReplacePart[temp, List /@ pos -> Nothing]};
    Echo[res, "res="];
    Sow[First@res];
    temp = Last@res]
   ][[-1, 1]]
 ]
```

[image]

---

Many variations are possible with regards to order. Here in this example, I have maintained the order in which the entries are extracted as well as retained at each iteration in both the lists.

The number of entries chunked at each iteration depends on the function applied and is typically not known in advance.

**Question(s)**

- I was wondering if there is a more functional way of doing this type of list chunking?
- Can this be done using a built-in function?
- Is there a standard name for this operation in functional programming?

Thanks for your help and suggestions in advance.

Comment: When the reomval operation respects an ordering relation, and all removals use that same relation, then this can be done using a priority queue. This is now a data structure built into the language; see ref/datastructure/PriorityQueue in the Documentation Center . Also there is [a reference implementation](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PriorityQueue/) in the Wolfram Function Repository.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this using NestWhileList. Inside this function you need TakeLargest and the Complement, to get rid of the taken elements:

t = {19, 4, 12, 1, 17, 13, 7, 14, 10, 11, 6, 18, 20, 15, 16, 3, 8, 5,
2, 9};

```
NestWhileList[{tmp = TakeLargest[#[[2]], 4], 
    Complement[#[[2]], tmp]} &, {{}, t}, Length[#[[2]]] >= 4 &][[2 ;;,
   1]]

(* {{20, 19, 18, 17}, {16, 15, 14, 13}, {12, 11, 10, 9}, {8, 7, 6, 
  5}, {4, 3, 2, 1}} *)
```

NestWhileList will return a list of tuples, where the first element are the 4 largest values and the second elements are the remaining values. We therefore only need the first element. We get rid of the first element of the output, because this is simply the input. All this is achieved by `[[2;;,1]]`

---

**EDIT** by @Syed

Thanks for your answer.

1. The solution uses set operations (i.e., `Complement`) and therefore sorting takes place.
2. Since the list may not be exactly divisible by the chunk size, I have made slight modifications to grab the leftover items. For instance for the case of a list with one more item `22` at location -7:

> ```
> t = {19, 4, 12, 1, 17, 13, 7, 14, 10, 11, 6, 18, 20, 15, 22, 16, 3, 8,
>     5, 2, 9};
> ```

```
NestWhileList[
  {tmp = TakeLargest[#[[2]], UpTo[4]], Complement[#[[2]], tmp]} &
  , {{}, t}
  , Length[#[[2]]] > 0 &][[2 ;;, 1]]
```

> ```
> {{22, 20, 19, 18}, {17, 16, 15, 14}, {13, 12, 11, 10}, {9, 8, 7, 
>   6}, {5, 4, 3, 2}, {1}}
> ```

---

To understand the `[[2;;,1]]`, use `Grid` at first to see the outputs at the successive stages of `NestWhileList`:

```
NestWhileList[
  {tmp = TakeLargest[#[[2]], UpTo[4]], Complement[#[[2]], tmp]} &
  , {{}, t}
  , Length[#[[2]]] > 0 &] // Grid
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'll just answer your first bullet point.

Evaluation code:

```
eval[func_]:=
ReleaseHold[Hold@func/.{
  f -> (TakeLargest[#, UpTo@4] &), 
  list -> {19,4,12,1,17,13,7,14,10,11,6,18,20,15,16,3,8,5,2,9}}
]
SetAttributes[eval, HoldAll]
```

First attempt:

```
eval@
  NestWhile[
   {Append[#[[1]],#[[2]][[First /@ #2]]],
    Delete[#[[2]], #2]} &
   [#,Position[#[[2]], Alternatives @@ f@#[[2]]]] &,
  {{},list},
  #[[2]] != {} &][[1]]
```

The `NestWhile` iterates on lists that contain `{{chunks so far},{elements to go}}`.  Naturally the start is `{{},list}`.  Keep going until the `{elements to go}` is empty.  At each step, `Append` the new chunk and `Delete` them (`Alternatives@@` is the magic thing here).

Second attempt:

```
eval@
 Reap[NestWhile[
  l \[Function] 
   DeleteCases[l, 
   Alternatives @@ Sow@SortBy[f@l, Position[l, #] &]], 
  list, # != {} &]][[2, 1]]
```

similar, but using `Reap`/`Sow`.  You can of course sort afterwards

```
eval[
SortBy[#, Position[list, #] &] & /@ 
 Reap[NestWhile[l \[Function] DeleteCases[l, 
  Alternatives @@ Sow@f@l],
 list, # != {} &]][[2, 1]]
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I will be studying your solution.

Answer (score 2):

A start, using `Sow` and `Reap`:

**Edit**

```
delSow[{x_List,y_List}]:= (Sow[x[[y]]];Delete[x,List/@y])

g=Function[{x,y},{x,Sort@TakeLargest[x->"Index", UpTo[y]]}]

(Reap@NestWhile[delSow@g[#,4]&, t, Length@#>1&])[[2]]//Catenate

(*{{19, 17, 18, 20}, {13, 14, 15, 16}, {12, 10, 11, 9}, {7, 6, 8, 5}, {4, 1, 3, 2}} *)

(Reap@NestWhile[delSow@g[#,7]&, t, Length@#>1&])[[2]]//Catenate

(* {{19, 17, 14, 18, 20, 15, 16}, {12, 13, 7, 10, 11, 8, 9}, {4, 1, 6, 3, 5, 2}} *)
```

**Original Answer**

```
f=Function[{x,y},(Sow[x[[#]]];Delete[x,List/@#])&@Sort@TakeLargest[x->"Index", UpTo[y]]]
```

Examples

```
Reap[NestWhile[f[#,4]&, t, Length@#>1&]][[2]]//Catenate


(* {{19, 17, 18, 20}, {13, 14, 15, 16}, {12, 10, 11, 9}, {7, 6, 8, 5}, {4, 1, 3, 2}} *) 


Reap[NestWhile[f[#,7]&, t, Length@#>1&]][[2]]//Catenate

{{19, 17, 14, 18, 20, 15, 16}, {12, 13, 7, 10, 11, 8, 9}, {4, 1, 6, 3, 5, 2}}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with x -> "Index". Could you please say more or point me to a link. I am amazed at the brevity of your code. (ok never mind, I have discovered it in the docs, but will have to study it further). Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same result simply by using `Partition` on the (reverse) sorted list:

```
Partition[ReverseSort@list,UpTo@4]
(* {{19,18,17,16},{15,14,13,12},{11,10,9,8},{7,6,5,4},{3,2,1}} *)
```

(Note that I removed the 20 from the list to show that it works when the length is not divisible by four)

If you want to reproduce the order of the original list, you can reapply it using `PositionIndex` as lookup for `SortBy`:

```
 SortBy[PositionIndex@list]/@Partition[ReverseSort@list,UpTo@4]
(* {{19,17,18,16},{12,13,14,15},{10,11,8,9},{4,7,6,5},{1,3,2}} *)
```

Comment: The idea is that the points can be collected using an algorithm and their partitions are not readily known. The `TakeLargest` example was a toy example. Look at my original post, where I keep the order in tact. So it is not possible in general to sort points in order or even know how many will be sifted by the algorithm per iteration.

Comment: @Syed sorry, it seems my reading of the question was too superficial - for your actual application, DanielHuber's answer is probably the best